# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel export file success, but the file is core dump

Tags: php, laravel-4

I use Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 1.1.5 with laravel 4.2.8 to export excel file. The file is exported success, but it is corrupt, (excel 2013 said that). How can I fix it?

Comment: Start by opening the file in a text editor, and reading any plaintext error messages in the file

Comment: I checked very carefully and only 'Unknown Creator' seem to be an error.

Comment: What exactly was the message that Excel2013 gave? What format of Excel file did you write? (xls, xlsx, etc)

Comment: The message is: "We found a proble with some content in 'file.xls'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes." I click Yes, a new message: "Unable to read the file", click Ok, new message: "The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt." If I click No in first message, nothing happen, nothing in excel. The same problem with xlsx file

Comment: In the text editor, look for any leading or trailing whitespace characters (space, tab, new lines, etc) in the file

Comment: There is no whitespace character. The end of file is: "R o o t   E n t r y                                               ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ           À      F    €¡˜ÌÏ€¡˜ÌÏ   @       S u m m a r y I n f o r m a t i o n                           (        ÿÿÿÿ       À      F                              W o r k b o o k                                                   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ       À      F                       ð       D o c u m e n t S u m m a r y I n f o r m a t i o n           8  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ       À      F                       ì       þ" and  500 character ÿ

Answer (score 6):

please add the following code above file return

```
ob_end_clean(); 
ob_start();
return Excel::download(new ExportRegIndNational, $file_name); //example
```

Comment: sir can you explain this  a bit , this is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP files of your Laravel project look for any trailing spaces before the `<?php` tag and delete them.

It seems that in all the chain of processing that has to occur in Laravel/PHP, if a PHP file has trailing spaces, those are chained and added to the final excel file. That results in a corrupt file.

So, open your favorite PHP editor, make a global search for  `<?php` (that's a space before the `<?php` tag) and you might find some of those offending trailing spaces. Delete them.

Answer (score -2):

Laravel 5 import export to excel and csv using maatwebsite

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-import-export-to-excel-and-csv-using-maatwebsite-exampleexample.html

And this link adds the controller file in the your controller name it works.